# Webpack AngularJS Sourcemaps issue

Tags: angularjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, source-maps

I've been struggling with getting my source-maps working in my app for quite a while. I have set

```
devtool:  'source-map',
```

in the webpack configuration, but they are still not available in the Chrome devtools.

[image]

I pushed a really simple app using my FE Stack hoping someone could identify the issue, whether it is with webpack, angular, or some other library. https://github.com/coreysnyder/Angular-Webpack3-Seed

Here are the versions I'm running:

```
{ 
  CoreyApp: '1.0.0',
  npm: '4.4.4',
  ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
  http_parser: '2.7.0',
  icu: '57.1',
  modules: '48',
  node: '6.9.0',
  openssl: '1.0.2j',
  uv: '1.9.1',
  v8: '5.1.281.84',
  zlib: '1.2.8' 
}
OSX 10.12.6
```

Comment: If i change `start-native` port to something like 8080 (because it can't start otherwise on my pc) and run`npm install` and `npm run start-native` everything works fine https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkfXN.png  and i can see source in the Chrome devtools

Comment: So if you throw a debugger into the view1.js  controller do you see the the breakpoint show up in the view1.js in chrome devtools? I am not having trouble finding the code in the console but rather having it show up on the controller.

Comment: Can you try with `devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map'` option?

Comment: I've tried with every option. Alas none result in helpful source maps making into the devtools.

Comment: Please list which OS you are using? Also node and npm versions

Comment: @TarunLalwani I've updated my question with Node/NPM & OSX versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably have to setup source map for different loaders individually.

For `'ng-annotate-loader'` ([Docs](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate/blob/master/OPTIONS.md#library-api))

```
use: [{
    loader: 'ng-annotate-loader',
    options: { 
        add: true, 
        single_quotes: true ,
        map: { inline: true, inFile: 'app.js', sourceRoot: __dirname + '/app' }}
}]
```

For `less` you can use [documentation](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/less-loader#source-maps) option like [@ahmedelgabri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47364318/1032167) suggested

```
use: [{
    loader: "style-loader"
}, {
    loader: "css-loader", options: {
        sourceMap: true
    }
}, {
    loader: "less-loader", options: {
        sourceMap: true
    }
}]
```

---

*Old post before OP github changes.*

Other option is to add [devtoolLineToLine: true](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-devtoollinetoline) in your [output](https://github.com/coreysnyder/Angular-Webpack3-Seed/blob/master/webpack.config.js#L194-L199), if you want to use `devtool: 'source-map'`. But devtoolLineToLine is deprecated, so consider changing `devtool` to something else.  [devtool: 'source-map' demo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hrr2.png)

```
output: isTest ? {} : {
    devtoolLineToLine: true, // <= this line

    sourceMapFilename: '[name].map',
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    publicPath: publicPath
},
```

---

Alternatively you could use `devtool: 'eval'` or some variation of eval, like `cheap-module-eval-source-map` (similar behavior, but without file names) [also works fine for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Wasx.png)

Comment: Closer, but still not working. I see "View 1 Ctrl" on `view1.js?:19` instead of line 23. Also I'm unable to set a breakpoint in my `doThing` function on line 27 of that same file. Are my expectations of sourcemaps off or are they just not working correctly.

Comment: @Corey are you using `babel-loader` from @scipper answer? Because i had the same issues with wrong line numbers.  Probably can try some advice from [here](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/207) or in my case i just dont have `loader: 'babel-loader'` part and use your initial source code

Comment: @Corey if that is the case, i think the easiest solution would be to use   retainLines: true option                  `{
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                            retainLines: true
                        }
                    }`

Answer (score 0):

I could fix your source maps for JS files, by adding the babel-loader. To do this, you need to install babel-loader:

```
npm i -D babel-loader@8.0.0-beta.0 @babel/core @babel/preset-env
```

and then extend your rule for .js

```
 rules: [
       {
         test: /\.js$/,
         exclude: /node_modules/,
         use: [
           {
             loader: 'ng-annotate-loader',
             options: { add: true, single_quotes: true }
           },
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
            }
          }
         ]
       }, [...]
 ]
```

Ready further details on [babel-loader github repo](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader)

Comment: When I use that I saw no changes. The console log "View 1 Ctrl" still appears as "app.js:19" instead of "view1.js:23"

Comment: Wht console log? Did I miss something?

Comment: https://github.com/coreysnyder/Angular-Webpack3-Seed/blob/master/app/views/view1/view1.js#L23

Comment: ah ok. well that‘s strange. I tried my fix with your project.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the Webpack config here https://github.com/coreysnyder/Angular-Webpack3-Seed

here is a gif using your code & setting a breakpoint in `view1` file

[image]

And here is why the text is blue

[image]

And I can see the source just fine

[image]

The main issue is the `less-loader` you need to pass the source-maps options for both, the `less-loader` & `css-loader` [check the readme](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/less-loader#source-maps)

```
  {
    test: /\.less$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'style-loader',
      },
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: true,
        },
      },
      {
        loader: 'less-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
```

After doing this you will be able to debug from the styles panel like this

[image]

If you want to edit directly the `.less` files the readme mentions a blog post that can help with this https://github.com/webpack-contrib/less-loader#source-maps

I hope this answers your question

Comment: You put the breakpoint in view.html which is a generated file by webpack. I'm trying to put breakpoints in the source via source maps. Putting breakpoints in the generated files is not helpful as the controller logic isn't broken out line-by-line.

Comment: When you see where the text is blue you're again seeing the compiled code, not the source. The only part that seems to be working is that you can see the stackOverflow service in an uncompiled state. That is what I'm trying to achieve for the view controllers as well which isn't happening.